# Java: How to open pop-up window from a class the GUI already delegates to?

Tags: java, swing, popupwindow, jdialog, delegation

I have several classes in my program, but for now we only have to worry about two of them:
GUI and Logics.

The GUI class delegates to the Logics class:

```
Logics logics = new Logics();
```

This is because I want the GUI class to call methods I have in the Logics class.

But now I also want a method in GUI to be called from the Logics class. Specifically I want the Logics to be able to make a pop-up box in the GUI class (JDialog) visible when some certain condition (that is checked in the Logics class) is fulfilled.

How do I go about doing this? I can't delegate from Logics to GUI, because then I will get an overflow (delegating back and forth into infinity).

Does anybody have any suggestions? :)

-Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of patterns out there for solving this exact class of problems.  They often leverage the Observer pattern.  For a start, read about [model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: @Mark IMO that comment could be an answer.

Comment: @MarkPeters
Yeh that was a very good answer, thanks. If you had posted it as an answer it would be the Accepted Answer ;) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the Logics class could be given a service for showing dialogs.  The GUI class could implement an Interface called DialogService (or whatever) that defines the methods for showing your dialogs.  You could then call:

```
Logics logics = new Logics(this);
```

without the need for the Logics class to have access to the GUI class directly.

Answer (score 0):

Deisgn an [Object Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_diagram) of both classes: Logics and GUI.

And then you need to figure out how you want the objects to interact with each via what interface. And what is the relationshp of objects with each other. Look into [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation), [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation) in the context Object Composition.